# Wavefront algorithm for area coverage

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, robotics

I am wondering whether the [Wavefront algorithm](http://www.societyofrobots.com/programming_wavefront.shtml) (or any other navigation algorithm), can be modified from trying to reach a a specific goal location to navigate to all reachable locations.

Any other advice on different types of WaveFront algorithm would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have visited your site. You stated that the robot can receive commands like "Go to ketchen". Well, I advice not to re-invent the wheel. Actually, you don't have to visit every cell, or "the hole area". Rather, you should select your shortest path to it, then walk through.

I believe [**Dijkstra's algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is much better for your robot path-finding.

An enhaced version of Dijkstra is [**A* algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star_algorithm), which takes less time in the average case.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DINCL5cd_w0) you can find examples how do they work, efficiently.

**EDIT:**

I have visited your site, again. You stated that you want an algorithm for navigating all the erea. Well, as far as I know, repeating A* algorithm will be much better. A* uses BFS, which has a better performance in the average case. It's very efficient when compared whith wavefront. The pseudocode is as following:

> - A) Find the shortest path with A* algorithm between the location and the goal
>
>   - B) If there is no way to the goal, specify a temp location and move to it. (Since you
>       indicated, it may find a way later). After arrived to temp location, Go to step A.
>   - C) Otherwise, if you have found a way, navigate to the target.

Comment: Thanks But unfortunately my question is that there is not sensor and pre-map for the robot and robot should make sure that every place is visited and cleaned. That's y path-finding in a way is pointless for this robot!

Comment: @FidEliO hmmm.. Why don't you give your robot prepared maps to the area? (e.g. a 2d array like yours: ones and zeros). It's very hard for the robot to visit every place

Comment: DDD THat's why I had in my mind but is there any other method for searching a whole area?

Comment: @FidEliO Do you want just to search? or walk through a whole area?

Comment: @DDD no i need to walk the whole area ... And I want the best algorithm, I might think of BFS,DFS. Any suggestions Mr. DDD?

Comment: @FidEliO A* uses best-first search. I'll edit my answer with new ideas.

Comment: @DDD as i said, the goal is to go every place and i assume that you cannot use such algorithms when you are navigating globally! am i wrong or right?

Answer (score 1):

This 1993 paper introduced a variant of the vanilla wave-front planner that achieves complete coverage, in addition to navigation from start to goal:

> A. Zelinsky, R.A. Jarvis, J.C. Byrne, S. Yuta, "Planning paths of
>   complete coverage of an unstructured environment by a mobile robot,"
>   Proceedings of the International Conference on Advanced Robotics,
>   1993, pp. 533-538.

Also see the following review paper for more ideas on coverage path planning:

> Enric Galceran, Marc Carreras, "A survey on coverage path planning for
>   robotics," Robotics and Autonomous Systems, Volume 61, Issue 12,
>   December 2013, Pages 1258-1276.